# Compute the series $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^6}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Compute the series $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^6}.$$

How do I go about with the index notation, for example to arrange the series instead as  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n $?

I have tried to simplify the expression as:

$$\begin{align}&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^6}=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)(n^3+n+1)}{n^6}\\
\implies&\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^6} - \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6} = \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)(n^3+n+1)}{n^6}\\
\implies& \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} - \sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}\end{align}$$

I'm not sure what to do with the index $n=3$ as I know that I can simplify it otherwise as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945}$.

Comment: You can do a simple index shift: $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^6}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(n+2)^4-1}{(n+2)^6}$. Just remember: If you lower/rise the index in the sum, you have to rise/lower it the same in the expression.

Comment: You have done the hard part (finding the values of $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{2}}$ and $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^{6}}$). To find the sums starting at $n=3$, just remove (subtract) the first two terms from each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have at least two options to transform your sum into a sum where the index goes from $1$ on.

One, you can use the fact that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_N + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n,$$

which can be shown from the definition of the infinite sum.

Or, you you can use the fact that

$$\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_n = \sum_{m=1}^\infty a_{k-1+m}.$$

which can be seen if you introduce a substitution $m=n+1-k$ (which also menas that $n=m+k-1$).

Comment: So I would get $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^-6} = \frac{(1)^4}{1^6} + \frac{(2^4-1)}{2^6} +\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^-6} $? but then how would I reduce the last sum?

Comment: @emilj.limes You already know how to calculate three out of the four terms in the equation you wrote in your comment.

Comment: Ah! I get it now, though I have a question on the second sum you mentioned; $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n-6} = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty} \frac{(m+3-1)^4-1}{(m+3-1)^6}$ what do I do with the $m+2$ terms?

Comment: @emilj.limes That second sum is not as useful as the first to calculate what you need. It is just an example of how to transform a sum to something that goes from $1$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Just "undo" the extraneous terms.

$$\sum_{n=3}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n-a_1-a_2.$$

> $$\frac{\pi^2}6-\frac54-\frac{\pi^6}{945}+\frac{65}{64}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4-1}{n^6}&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{n^4}{n^4}\frac{1-\frac{1}{n^4}}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1-\frac{1}{n^4}}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^6}\\
\end{align}$$

Now note, since each limit exists (see below, for the value)

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{5}{4}$$

$$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{65}{64}$$

You can split up the sum

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^6}&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}-\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^6}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{5}{4}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}+\frac{65}{64}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{\pi^6}{945}-\frac{15}{64}\\
\end{align}$$

The calculation of the limits above is done in the following manner:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{6}&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{1}{1^2}+\frac{1}{2^2}\\
&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{5}{4}\\
\end{align}$$

Subtracting $\frac{5}{4}$ on both sides, yields

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi^2}{6}-\frac{5}{4}&=\sum_{n=3}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}
\end{align}$$