# Prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{3}{4}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Prove $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{3}{4}$ using:

1. $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}[f(n+1)-f(n-1)] = \lim_{n \to \infty}[f(n)+f(n+1)]-f(1)-f(2)$

What I have tried:
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2-1} = \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{(n-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)} \right)$$

I've recently learnt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4290831/compute-the-series-sum-n-3-infty-fracn4-1n6) that I can do this:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots + a_N + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty a_n,$$

$$\implies \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)}-\frac{1}{(n+1)} \right)-\frac{1}{4}$$

How do I proceed from here (only hints)?

Comment: Take $f(n)=-\frac 1 {2n}$

Comment: Why'd you use the bound $n=1$? $n-1=0$ if $n=1$, which means $\frac{1}{n-1}$ is undefined, but if you look at your original series there isn't a division by 0 present.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy When I plug this in I get $-\frac{3}{4}$ do I put the minus sign into the series so I get the reverse order $-(\frac{1}{n-1}-\frac{1}{n+1}) = \frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n-1}$? which should give $\frac{3}{4}$?

Comment: @Kyky I think I still need some more practice with these questions to fully understand what they're asking. But I think I'm getting it now

Comment: @Kyky I think that I get it better now. Because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}[f(n+1) - f(n)] = \lim_{n \to \infty} f(n) - f(1)$ so when $(n-1)$ at $n=1$ is 0, we're just left with $\frac{1}{n+1}$ and as given here it represents $f(1) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n=1}$, therefore $-(f1)-f(2) = \frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Not quite. As others have pointed out, there isn't a good choice of $f$ such that $\frac{1}{n^2-1}=f(n)-f(n-1)$. Henno's explained it better than I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the series $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (f(n+1)-f(n-1))$ for $f(n)=-\frac{1}{2n}$. So your formula under 1. gives (noting that both limits are $0$): $-f(1)-f(2) = -(-\frac{1}{2}) - (-\frac{1}{4})$. I see no issues.

Comment: Check my latest comment, your answered helped puzzle this together

Answer (score 1):

Why not do like this. First calculate the finite summation $S_N$ and then take the limit $N\rightarrow\infty$:
$$ S_N=\sum_{n=2}^N\frac1{n^2-1}=\frac12\sum_{n=2}^N\left(\frac1{n-1}-\frac1{n+1}\right)=\frac12\left(1+\frac12-\frac1N-\frac1{N+1}\right).
$$
Now you can take the limit
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}S_N=\frac34$$